# Django: following relationships "backward" with multiple models

Tags: python, django

I have a set of models similar to this, where both Novel and Magazine have a `ForeignKey` to Bookshelf:

```
class Bookshelf(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Novel(models.Model):
    bookshelf = models.ForeignKey(Bookshelf)

class Magazine(models.Model):
    bookshelf = models.ForeignKey(Bookshelf)
```

Following relationships backward according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward), I know I can use two `Managers`: `bookshelf.novel_set` and `bookshelf.magazine_set`.

But **what is the best way to get a single set of Novels AND Magazines** on a Bookshelf? My actual setup has a growing list of models like this. Running the same operations on many "_sets" seems unpythonic and way too much boilerplate.

I've looked at `GenericRelation` and writing a custom `Manager`, but neither seems to do what I need cleanly (I may be wrong). Using Django 3.2.

Comment: The canonical way is to use a base class

Comment: @Marat I'm already using an abstract base class for these, but they still have their own DB tables and can't be grouped into a single set.

Comment: [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) are using the same DB table

Comment: It could be an option, but I already have years of data in these separate tables and migrating to a single one seems impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Each Model maps to one DB table. Which is restrictive.

THe buzzword is "polymorphic models". You want a table that can represent both books and magazines. So far as they are similar in most other respects, you can accomplish this with

```
class BookshelfItem( models.Model)
    NOVEL = 'Novel'
    MAGAZINE = 'Magazine'
    BOOKSHELF_ITEM_TYPES = ( (NOVEL, 'Novel'), (MAGAZINE, 'Magazine'), )

    item_type = models.CharField( choices = BOOKSHELF_ITEM_TYPES, ...)
    bookshelf = models.ForeignKey(Bookshelf, related_name='items')
    ...
```

Now you can get a list of both with `bookshelf.items` and a list of a chosen one with `bookshelf.items.filter( item_type = BookShelfItem.MAGAZINE )`. You can even define more managers on the `Bookshelf` model to make it possible to do `Bookshelf.magazines.filter(...)` etc.

Where the items start being grossly dissimilar and cause you to have large numbers of often null or blank fields, you realize why there are other approaches to paper over this fundamental limitation with relational databases.

Comment: What are these other approaches? These models already inherit from a single abstract base class but extend it in unique ways, lumping them all together like this would be a mess.

Comment: @kontextify You can use concrete model inheritance, with the efficiency penalty of a OneToOne link between two tables. You can use a single JSONField to store all the data which is not common between all models (with PostgreSQL, JSONB is efficiently searchable with Querysets and Postgres extensions). You can even go NoSQL/ FrankenDjango (eeek)! JSONB/Postgres is the only one I have used.